# typeerror in basic example for legend handles in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have difficulties to understand the legend handling. The more, the basic example from the official [matplotlib legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label='Line 2')
line_down, = plt.plot([3,2,1], label='Line 1')
plt.legend(handles=[line_up, line_down])
```

fails with `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'handles'`.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

My matplotlib version is `1.3.1`. I am on Ubuntu 14.04..

Here is the full traceback (with the above lines in the python script)

```
heiland@note121:bauHS15_iomapsgenpod$ python testleg.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testleg.py", line 4, in <module>
    plt.legend(handles=[line_up, line_down])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3381, in legend
    ret = gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4778, in legend
    self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'handles'
```

Comment: That is odd...Can you post the _full_ trace back?

Comment: sure, I have added it to the question body.

Comment: I can not reproduce this on 1.4.0.  This was either a bug that was already fixed or something really funny is going on with your installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just remove `handles` keyword

Use it like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
line_up, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label='Line 2')
line_down, = plt.plot([3,2,1], label='Line 1')
plt.legend([line_up, line_down])
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue as Jan, running Matplotlib 1.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried the answer posted by Kobi K. His code did not raise any errors. However, the legend did not render correctly: 
[image: Bad legend via Matplotlib 1.3.1]
I upgraded to Matplotlib 1.5.1, and can now render the legend correctly using the code posted by Jan, which includes the 'handles' keyword (i.e. the code that appears in the [Matplotlib legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)):
[image: Bad legend via matplotlib 1.5.1]

Comment: Not that I know of. It shouldn't take too long to increase your reputation. I see you're trying to be helpful, but a) the "answer" doesn't conform to the answer policy, which why I made the recommendation, b) there doesn't seem to be a way to remove my review now that it's been entered, and c) two other people made the same recommendation, but weren't nice enough to leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error some while back, but the fixes suggested above didn't work for me. I updated my version of matplotlib as well, but this didn't help.

What did work was removing the handles argument and which plots to label altogether in the legend() method; like this:

```
    plot1 = plt.plot([1,2,3], 'b', label = 'first plot')
    plot2 = plt.plot([3,2,1], 'r', label = 'second plot')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Which rendered nicely to this:
[image]