# Matplotlib plots legend on one machine but not the other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Python script that plots an electronic band structure with a corresponding legend of color patches, as shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axbGk.png) It works fine on my machine but when my colleague tried to run the script on his machine using the same input files, matplotlib plots the band structure correctly but fails to create the legend. He tried running in both Python 2 and 3 and received the same error: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py:4747: UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.

Since we are using the same input files/code, I don't know why it is working on one machine but not the other. Any idea of what might be causing this issue and how to fix it? Many thanks.

Here is the part of code that is supposed to create the legend.

```
    r_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='r', label='dxy')       

    b_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='b', label='dyz') 

    y_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='y', label='dz2') 

    g_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='g', label='dxz') 

    m_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='m', label='dx2-y2')

    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=5, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0., handles=[r_patch, b_patch, y_patch,g_patch, m_patch])
```

Comment: Is the version of matplotlib the same?

Comment: Also check any differences in matplotlibrc files between the two machines

Comment: Tried with python 2.7.13 and matplotlib 1.5.3, using the Tk and the Qt4 backend. Both plotted correctly. You might want to check versions and setups between the machines.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error.
Is something related with matplotlib versions.

See next page:
[Matplotlib Legend Guide basic examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792123/matplotlib-legend-guide-basic-examples)

Could you try next change?:

```
r_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='r')       

b_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='b') 

y_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='y') 

g_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='g') 

m_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='m')

plt.legend([r_patch, b_patch, y_patch,g_patch, m_patch],
           ['dxy','dyz','dz2','dzx','dx2-y2'],
           bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=5, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
```