# How to put the legend on first subplot of seaborn.FacetGrid?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` which I visualize with subplots of a [`seaborn.barplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.barplot.html). *My problem is that I want to move my legend inside one of the subplots.*

To create subplots based on a condition (in my case *Area*), I use [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid). This is the code I use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
# .. load data
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Area", col_order=['F1','F2','F3'])
bp = grid.map(sns.barplot,'Param','Time','Method')
bp.add_legend()
bp.set_titles("{col_name}")
bp.set_ylabels("Time (s)")
bp.set_xlabels("Number")
sns.plt.show()
```

Which generates this plot:

[image: barplot-all]

You see that the legend here is totally at the right, but I would like to have it inside one of the plots (for example the left one) since my original data labels are quite long and the legend occupies too much space. This is the example for only 1 plot where the legend is inside the plot:

[image: barplot1]

and the code:

```
mask = df['Area']=='F3'
ax=sns.barplot(x='Param',y='Time',hue='Method',data=df[mask])
sns.plt.show()
```

---

**Test 1**:
I tried the example of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32301804/1771479) where they have the legend in one of the subplots:

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Area", col_order=['F1','F2','F3'])
bp = grid.map(sns.barplot,'Param','Time','Method')
Ax = bp.axes[0]
Boxes = [item for item in Ax.get_children()
     if isinstance(item, matplotlib.patches.Rectangle)][:-1]
legend_labels  = ['So1', 'So2', 'So3', 'So4', 'So5']
# Create the legend patches
legend_patches = [matplotlib.patches.Patch(color=C, label=L) for
              C, L in zip([item.get_facecolor() for item in Boxes],
                          legend_labels)]

# Plot the legend
plt.legend(legend_patches)    
sns.plt.show()
```

Note that I changed `plt.legend(handles=legend_patches)` did not work for me therefore I use `plt.legend(legend_patches)` as commented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551618/1771479). The result however is:

[image: bar test with legend in 3rd]

As you see the legend is in the third subplot and neither the colors nor labels match.

---

**Test 2**:

Finally I tried to create a subplot with a column wrap of 2 (`col_wrap=2`) with the idea of having the legend in the right-bottom square:

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="MapPubName", col_order=['F1','F2','F3'],col_wrap=2)
```

but this also results in the legend being at the right:

[image: barplot 2cols]

---

**Question**: How can I get the legend inside the first subplot? Or how can I move the legend to anywhere in the grid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the legend on the specific axes you want, by using `grid.axes[i][j].legend()`

For your case of a `1 row, 3 column` grid, you want to set `grid.axes[0][0].legend()` to plot on the left hand side.

Here's a simple example derived from your code, but changed to account for the sample dataset.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="day")
bp = grid.map(sns.barplot,"time",'total_bill','sex')

grid.axes[0][0].legend()

bp.set_titles("{col_name}")
bp.set_ylabels("Time (s)")
bp.set_xlabels("Number")
sns.plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @Rockbar it works for me with seaborn 0.8.1; what version are you using?

Comment: I have the same version. note: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing

Comment: Looks like you only have one subplot? Did you copy the example above or is this in your own code? If you only have one subplot, you don't need the [0][0]

Comment: Actually, I am using a very very similar code with Facetgrid and map, but instead of sns.barplot a extended function including plt.scatter. I will try sns.regplot, alternatively.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use the `legend_out=False` option.
2. If you are making a faceted bar plot, you should use `factorplot` with `kind=bar`. Otherwise, if you don't explicitly specify the order for each facet, it is possible that your plot will end up being wrong.

   ```
   import seaborn as sns
   tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
   sns.factorplot(x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", col="day",
                  data=tips, kind="bar", aspect=.7, legend_out=False)
   ```

[image]

Comment: Hi! great package! how would you move the legend to another of the facets with this option?

Comment: Also, is it possible to move the legend to an empty place of the FacetGrid? say you have 3 plots, in a 2x2 grid like in the agold question