# Changing legend location seaborn factorplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet", data=exercise)
```

In seaborn, is there a way to plot the legend in the first sub-plot instead of second? This example is from here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html?highlight=factor#seaborn.factorplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an even easier way:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet",
                   data=exercise, legend_out=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following should work.

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind",
              col="diet", data=exercise, legend=False)
g.axes[0][0].legend()
```

PS:

1. [How to put the legend on first subplot of seaborn.FacetGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631163/how-to-put-the-legend-on-first-subplot-of-seaborn-facetgrid)