# How to add legends to sns subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

Desired Outcome:

[image: Diserd outcome]

So I was trying to add legends to the subplots,
I tried to add ax[0].legend() to the code, but it raise "No handles with labels found to put in legend."

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 6))
ax = ax.flatten()
sns.histplot(train[train['Survived'] == 0]['Age'], ax=ax[0])
sns.histplot(train[train['Survived'] == 1]['Age'], color='red', alpha=0.4, ax=ax[0])
sns.histplot(train[train['Survived'] == 0]['Fare'], ax=ax[1])
sns.histplot(train[train['Survived'] == 1]['Fare'], color='red', alpha=0.4, ax=ax[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631163/how-to-put-the-legend-on-first-subplot-of-seaborn-facetgrid

Comment: I have seen the post already. However, I don't have a grid object in my code. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know what to do now:

```
ax[0].legend(['Survived', 'Not Survived'])
ax[1].legend(['Survived', 'Not Survived'])
```

[image: Answer]