# How to move figure-level matplotlib legend to axes of a seaborn displot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am calling `sns.displot` to get a `FacetGrid`

```
g = sns.displot(
    data=df_all,
    x='a_number',
    hue='a_condition',
    row='a_factor',
    col='another_factor',
    stat="density", 
    common_norm=False,
    element='step',
    palette=palette,
)
```

Similar to this question, I want to place the automatically-generated legend on one of the axes, instead of outside them as a figure-level legend:
[How to put the legend on first subplot of seaborn.FacetGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631163/how-to-put-the-legend-on-first-subplot-of-seaborn-facetgrid?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Just calling `g.fig.axes[row][col].legend()` does not work:

```
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

So I should generate the handles and labels?
I looked at how `Grid.add_legend` does this and it seems to be some magic that would require me knowing a lot more about how the class works to reproduce it (maybe I am wrong). There's also no `_legend_data` I can use to dynamically recreate the legend in the same way that the `Grid.add_legend` method does.

```
>>> g._legend_data

{}
```

The "easy" (lazy?) way would be if I could somehow copy the `legend` instance, add that copy to the axes I want, and then call `g.fig._legend.remove()` (unless anyone has any better ideas)

I can't figure out how to copy the legend and then assign it to a specific `Axes`.

Comment: Do you care about which axes it goes in? Or is it ok if it goes in the first? If the latter, there is `facet_kws=dict(legend_out=False)`. If the former, more tricky, but there's a recipe for "moving" a legend within a single axes plot [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2280#issuecomment-692350136) that should be straightforward to adapt to your case.

Comment: (Even if you want the legend to end up somewhere else, I'd probably set `legend_out=False` either way, because it will avoid the figure resize that happens to support an external legend.)

Comment: That comment in the GitHub issue looks exactly like what I wanted, thank you @mwaskom

Answer (score 1):

It dawned on me I could just call `g.legend.set_bbox_to_anchor()` as a workaround.

In this case the legend is still figure-level but it lets me get it where I want it.

edit:
@mwaskom replied with a link to this comment on a GitHub issue, that has a code snippet that does what I had in mind:
https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2280#issuecomment-692350136

for my purposes I tweaked it like so

```
def move_legend(g, ax, new_loc, **kws):
    old_legend = g.legend
    handles = old_legend.legendHandles
    labels = [t.get_text() for t in old_legend.get_texts()]
    title = old_legend.get_title().get_text()
    ax.legend(handles, labels, loc=new_loc, title=title, **kws)

move_legend(g, g.fig.axes[-2], "upper right")
g.legend.remove()
```

relevant discussion of what's going on under the hood is on that issue

Comment: BTW the figure-level legend is a public attribute (`g.legend`) since v0.11.0.